Setting up Transactional Replication - Can i safely remove transactional replication if it is causing issues on my publisher?
Please excuse me if I am not making very much sense here. I am very new to replication and have been researching for quite some time about transactional replication to implement in our scenario..
I am trying to consider all the options before setting up transactional replication on my 2008R2 server to 2012 distribution server to 2012 Subscriber server. All the three servers are on FULL recovery mode. Log backup is taken every 15 minutes and full backup is taken daily everyday on all the three server databases used in replication. We want to use the subscriber as a reporting server. Publisher is our main OLTP database
What special considerations should I keep in mind before implementing transactional replication on my production environment.
What queries should I use after setting up this replication to monitor the log space use, IO usage, CPU usage on my publisher? How often should i user these queries- should I run them on a regular schedule via a sql agent job on hourly/daily basis?
What if the publisher database gets performance issues after the replication is setup? If I have to remove transactional replication - would it affect my publisher in any ways like would the T-logs be affected or would they be un-affected and would get backed up like normal (as it was before replication) or would it break the t-log chain of the publisher if the replication is removed?

Can i safely remove transactional replication if it is causing issues on my publisher?
I am answering your broad question first. The answer is yes. You can follow Manually remove replication in SQL Server by Microsoft.
What special considerations should I keep in mind before implementing transactional replication on my production environment.
You should test it in a nonproduction environment before doing it in production. These documents should help you to get started:

Tutorial: Configure replication between two fully connected servers (transactional)
Measure Latency and Validate Connections for Transactional Replication
Troubleshooter: Find errors with SQL Server transactional replication

What queries should I use after setting up this replication to monitor the log space use, IO usage, CPU usage on my publisher? How often should i user these queries- should I run them on a regular schedule via a sql agent job on hourly/daily basis?
Your monitoring for standard performance metrics does not change because you are adding replication. You need to get a new baseline and adjust your alert thresholds.
You must pay attention to some of the replication-specific monitoring mentioned in the abovementioned documents.
What if the publisher database gets performance issues after the replication is setup? If I have to remove transactional replication - would it affect my publisher in any ways like would the T-logs be affected or would they be un-affected and would get backed up like normal (as it was before replication) or would it break the t-log chain of the publisher if the replication is removed?
You will be okay with removing replication following Microsoft documentation. Transaction log chain will NOT be impacted.

Thanks SqlWWorldWide. If the Subscriber goes down, then the publisher will still function but the commands to get replicated will be queuing up depending upon the retention setup and how long the subscriber is down. How should I maintain this in order to not put load on the publisher?

Also, what will happen if the subscriber goes down- will the logs keep accumulating on the publisher? I have not used 'Sync with Backup' on publisher or Distributor

Do you mind ask these as a new questions? Comments should not be used for question and answer.
